# Add ylab to ggplot plots in a list

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I have a set of boxplots in a list using something of the form:

```
data(mtcars)
box_stack <- function(metrics){
  ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(y = metrics, x = factor(1))) + geom_boxplot() + 
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=5, size=4)
}

box_list_stack <- lapply(c("disp","hp"),function(metric){box_stack(metric)})
do.call(grid.arrange, c(box_list_stack,ncol=2))
```

Unfortunately `disp` and `hp` are not the labels I want (but are the variable names). So, I'd like to amend the ylabs. I'm trying to do a lapply, along the lines of:

```
box_list <- lapply(1:2,function(var_n) {
  var_name <- c("Real_disp_name","Real_hp_name")[[var_n]]
  var_org <- c("disp","hp")[[var_n]]
  #box_list[[var_org]][[9]][[2]] <<- var_name
  box_list[[var_n]][[9]][[2]] <<- var_name
  }
                       )
```

The `[[x]][[9]][[2]]` is the bit of the list I want to assign, but 
doing it as above (either of the last 2 lines) replaces the whole list element.

Comment: We cld prbly help you make facets vs use `grid.arrange` if we had some data.

Comment: Ended up doing it manually (on a deadline), have worked out a data example now.